# Laravel Getting Filename from javascript/ajax FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, upload

I'm trying to get the original filename from a FormData object being uploaded to my server, but cant for the life of me figure out how to access that.

My js/ajax is like so:

```
function AjaxFileUpload(files, progressBar, target, id, imageContainer){

//Creates a formdata object for the upload, appends a CSRF token, the file itself and its respective name
var formData = new FormData;
formData.append('_token', CSRF_TOKEN);
formData.append('target', target);
formData.append('id', id)
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
  formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
}

$.ajax({
  url: '/upload',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
```

And it is handled on the serverside using in my upload controller like so:

```
public function upload(Request $request){

    $arr = [];
    foreach($request->all() as $file){
      if(is_file($file)){

        //$file_type = mime_content_type($file);

        $size = filesize($file);
        $ext = $file->guessExtension();
        //Do some stuff
```

The code works fine, but I just have no idea how to get the file name on the PHP side.

Comment: Are you allowing dynamic field names or something?  You should use $request->file() to get the file object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $file->guessExtension(); is working properly, then you should be able to get the filename via:  $file->getClientOriginalName(); This is documented in the [Other File Methods methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files) link to the [Symfony documentation](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalName) for the UploadedFile class

Comment: Beautiful! sorry for the late reply, I'll  try this immediately